# Change color of caret SwiftUI TextField MacOS

Tags: macos, colors, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to change the color of the caret in a SwiftUI textfield.

I tried:

```
.accentColor(Color.init(red: 0.34, green: 0.31, blue: 0.23, opacity: 1.00))
```

But I get an error stating "'accentColor' is unavailable in macOS". Any way to achieve the same goal in MacOS? .foregroundColor only changes text colour but not the caret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is worked solution. Tested with Xcode 12b

[image: demo]

```
if #available(OSX 10.16, *) {
    TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$text)
       .accentColor(.red)
} else {
    TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$text)
       .colorMultiply(.red)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available yet. I submitted `FB8988194` to Apple to make it so `accentColor` sets the cursor color like on iOS.

The only way to do it is to use a `NSViewRepresentable` and set it in your `NSTextField` like this:

```
struct YourCustomField: NSViewRepresentable{
  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextField {
    let textField = FancyTextField()
    ...
  }
  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {
    ...
  }
}

class FancyTextField: NSTextField {
  override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    let textView = window?.fieldEditor(true, for: nil) as? NSTextView
    textView?.insertionPointColor = NSColor(named: "YourColorName")!
    
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
}
```

If anyone knows of a pure-SwiftUI way, I'm eager to learn of it.